# Is it common in SE to get downvotes on questions with many good-quality answers?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm SE user for about a year or so and recently I started to contribute to [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7885/trejder?tab=questions).

I've noticed, that on that site many of [my questions gets downvoted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/52349/7885), though it generate fairly big interest and many, good quality or [even perfect answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52447/7885).

This is a little bit strange for me. I don't recall the same happening on other SE sites. Either question is poor (so it gets downvoted) or it is good enough to bring enough attention (so it gets many answers).

I even heard somewhere (though I can't recall were and maybe I misunderstood something), that if you sit down to write a long, good-quality, detailed answer, it is a good polite to voteup a question, assuming -- that if it brought enough attention on your side, to write such a long and good answer, it seems to be good itself and worth upvoting.

Can anyone answer (maybe bring some figures) what is more common? Is it natural, that question gets dovnwoted, tough it generates quite large interest and have more than one answer with a few votes?

Comment: You probably want to ask this on the SF&F meta, as this question is really about why your SF&F questions are downvotes. I'm sure they'd be able to give you a more specific and helpful answer. (Flagged for migration)

Comment: This is an extreme example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly -147 on the question, +683 on the answer. So your case does not seem unique...

Comment: @Emracool I'm not sure, if this should be asked on SF&F meta, as I'm asking about general behavior on SE (and user00001 has convinced me, that there is nothing unusual in this). I have both upvoted and downvoted questions in SF&F and I was just curious, how often it happens that questions gets many downvotes, while its answers has many upvotes?

Comment: @user000001 Maybe you should reformulate this to an answer, so I can pick it, because your example is actually a perfect answer to my question...

Comment: @trejder Ah, alright. Just be prepared for an answer which does not at all address why your questions are receiving downvotes :P

Comment: This isn't exactly unique to SF&F - It happens on SO, Programmers, Movies, Money ... I have an answer to this that I can't _quite_ articulate properly, but I will stop back and take a crack at it later.

Comment: @Emracool I don't care for the downvotes (especially those without sufficient comment coming with)! :] But, the general explanation, how often this happens (and if it is considered normal) would be great.

Comment: @TimPost All right, waiting for you to try to _crack_ it, so I can pick the best answer for this question (didn't ever thought, that such question will bring so much attention, feared rather, that it will be... downvoted and closed! :])

Answer (score 4):

Yes, having downvoted questions receiving upvoted answers is rather common.

Usually people vote on the quality of each post, without considering if it is answer to a "bad" question.

As to why people answer questions that get downvoted, it is because we answer (mostly) for future readers, and not only for the original asker. So a poorly researched question can get answered, because the answer will still help lots of people in the future.

An example of a downvoted question (-147) with an upvoted answer (+683) is this: [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

There is even a gold badge ([Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal)) that encourages this behavior.